# How can I query Active Directory in .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, ldap

I want to query Active Directory in a .NET Core project and get details of a user by providing the user id.

LDAP server path is in this format: `ldap://`

Answer (score 5):

The [LDAP URLs](https://www.ldap.com/ldap-urls) specifies  the server you want to use and the query to perform. For instance, in the query:

```
ldap://ds.example.com:389/dc=example,dc=com?givenName,sn,cn?sub?(uid=john.doe)
```

- `ds.example.com:389` comprises the LDAP server and port.
- `dc=example,dc=com` is the base DN
- `givenName,sn,cn` are the attributes to include in the result,
- `sub` is the scope, and
- `(uid=john.doe)` is the query

There is an [LDAP library in .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx), that is [not included in .NET Core](https://long2know.com/2017/06/net-core-ldap/). You may use the [Novell LDAP libraries](https://www.novell.com/documentation/developer/ldapcsharp/?page=/documentation/developer/ldapcsharp/cnet/data/bovtvq9.html) to query an LDAP and/or Active Directory Server in .NET Core. The documentation is available [at Novell](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/11204.html).

The documentation for the Novell library [mentions the LDAP URLs](https://www.novell.com/documentation/developer/ldapcsharp/?page=/documentation/developer/ldapcsharp/cnet/data/b3u1s5w.html). If you have LDAP URLs, I think you must split the URL to obtain each part and perform the query.

---

**Getting information of a user**

Using the Novell library, you can can connect to the server and perform [LDAP queries](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) using attributes of the entries such as in queries like `(givenName=John)`, `(!givenName=John)` or `(givenName=Jo*)`.  You may check the example code [here](https://nicolas.guelpa.me/blog/2017/02/15/dotnet-core-ldap-authentication.html), [here](https://long2know.com/2017/06/net-core-ldap/) and [here](https://auth0.com/blog/using-ldap-with-c-sharp/).

In Windows / Active Directory, the login name is stored in `sAMAccountName`. You can use a query like

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName={0}))
```